# Are there any linux distros that have the bitcoin client pre-included?

Tags: client, linux

Ideally would be able to make a bootable usb with a lightweight linux os which already included the bitcoin client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LinuxCoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/LinuxCoin) is such a distro (based on Debian).

Comment: looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It doesn't give a very professional impression unfortunately. What version of the Bitcoin client will I get if I download their LinuxCoin 0.2-final (or 0.2b-final, or 0.2.1b)? The main page of the wiki is just a page full of spam.

Comment: @D.H. True, I would perfer installing a clean linux, then securely downloading the latest Bitcoin release.

Answer (score 4):

Since LinuxCoin doesn't seem to updated very frequently, here are instructions for creating a custom bootable USB with the [MCNLive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCNLive) distribution on it. You add whatever programs you want and it can then create a new .iso file for you to use for your USB.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/make-your-own-portable-mandriva-flash/

Answer (score 4):

BitSafe is an opensource Debian based lightweight live distro designed to provide a multilanguage, easy and secure live environment for Bitcoin.

It has a lot of innovative features like:

- Onscreen keyboard to thwart keyloggers
- Encrypted storage partition for wallet and client
- Tor tunneling capabilities
- Minimal number of applications and installed packages to reduce attack surface

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=46916.0

https://github.com/rb1205/BitSafe

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is a most popular Debian fork have bitcoind package in official repository:

```
# dpkg -l bitcoind
ii  bitcoind  0.8.1-1   amd64    peer-to-peer network based digital currency - daemon
```

More info:

```
# aptitude show bitcoind
Package: bitcoind                        
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 0.8.1-1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/utils
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 3,126 k
Depends: libboost-filesystem1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1), libboost-program-options1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1), libboost-system1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1), libboost-thread1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1), libc6 (>= 2.15), libdb5.1++, libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1),
         libleveldb1, libminiupnpc8 (>= 1.6), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.6)
Suggests: db-util, db4.8-util
Conflicts: bitcoind
Description: peer-to-peer network based digital currency - daemon
 Bitcoin is a free open source peer-to-peer electronic cash system that is completely decentralized, without the need for a central server or trusted parties.  Users hold the crypto keys to their own money and transact directly
 with each other, with the help of a P2P network to check for double-spending. 

 By default connects to an IRC network to discover other peers. 

 Full transaction history is stored locally at each client.  This requires several GB of space, slowly growing. 

 This package provides bitcoind, a combined daemon and CLI tool to interact with the daemon.
Homepage: http://www.bitcoin.org
```

Comment: This is a distribution that has Bitcoin in the package repository, but that's not the same as it being pre-included.

Comment: Creation of "bootable usb image" is easy task with Ubuntu. It is exactly what Asking want to achieve.